# Firefox add-on to block browser caching but have exceptions for individual whitelisted domains/URLs?

Tags: firefox, privacy, url, caching, browser-extension

[I have a good reason to want to disable caching by default in my browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4960/will-disabling-caching-in-tor-browser-increase-anonymity-or-decrease-it).

(It's a particular approach to privacy, whereby for sites I don't visit that often or log into, disabling cache prevents them from knowing whether I have visited their site at any time before, or another one that has cross-site objects loading, either.)

However, I've come to see that sometimes, it's *more* in my privacy interests to have any cross-site objects that I use a lot, to be SAVED in cache, so that after the first download so I am not re-pinging (to re-download) those objects every time I browse other websites referencing them, thus announcing to that third-party website every page that I'm visiting on the web when using it.

So I am in need, of a way to control what is cached, and what isn't, in Firefox.

Is there some add-on that can do essentially do rule-based '**firefox cache control**', or to put it another way, a rules-based '**firefox cache blocker**'?

I can find Firefox add-ons that do the *opposite* - custom exceptions to (the normal) 'caching allowed' by BLOCKING caching for individual sites - but not the other way - ALLOWING cache, for ONLY certain sites (or URLs) where the default is to *not* store cache.

Comment: There is a similar topic on superuser:
http://superuser.com/questions/333107/have-an-add-on-for-firefox-like-noscript-but-for-cookies-that-make-possible-to

Answer (score 0):

I know a good proxy server (e.g., Squid) will do this, either for one PC or for a whole network; one could set Firefox's cache at zero and depend on Squid to do the job.